# How to trace a spline in the middle of an irregular curved street?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm creating a program that should drive a car through the middle of a street.

The street, as shown below, is a bitmap with irregular curves.

I would like my program to calculate a central route, that is, that it finds the middle between each side of the street, where would be the orientation for the passage of the car.

[image]

The problem is that the algorithm has to identify what a curve is and in addition, know at what angle the curve points, to from there find its center.

Would anyone give me a tip?

Comment: For each white point determine whether it is closer to the "lower" or the "upper" black blob. I suppose, you want your blue curve to be the boundary between these two regions

Comment: The blue line would be the ideal path resulting from finding the middle of the street. Finding the white point close to the lower or upper black blob is correct for 0 degrees, but how it could be done to find what is a curve and its middle?